# How to resolve the file processing issue during docker volume mount in linux?

Tags: linux, docker, unix, docker-volume, docker-container

I am trying to containerize my application. The application basically process files and place it in a different folder after renaming it. The source folder "opt/fileprocessing/input" and target it "opt/fileprocessing/output"

Scenario 1. - without volume mount
When I start my docker container and place file in the source folder us docker cp command, the application process it and place it successfully in the target folder

Scenario 2 . - with volume mount with the host

```
docker run -d -v /opt/input:/opt/fileprocessing/input -v /opt/output:/opt/fileprocessing/output --name new_container processor
```

when I place the file in the /opt/input folder of the host, the application throws an error that it cant place the file in the destination. If I go inside the container and view the input folder I see the file in the input folder that confirms that the mount has happened succesfullu.It fails when renaming and posting it in the destination (well this is application level code error , no much help there I get).

I tried the following to make it work.

1. Made sure the host and container users are the same and has the same uid and gid
2. File has 775 permission set.
3. The container folder has 777 permission
4. Same file has been placed that was used for scenario 1.
5. File name same and format as well
6. container OS

   NAME="CentOS Linux"
   VERSION="8"
   ID="centos"
   ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
   VERSION_ID="8"
   PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
7. host os

   NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
   VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
   ID="rhel"
   ID_LIKE="fedora"
   VARIANT="Server"

Scenario - 3 - Mounted the file in a different way , as below

```
docker run -d -v /opt/fileprocessing:/opt/fileprocessing -v /opt/fileprocessing:/opt/fileprocessing --name new_container processor
```

while the fileprocessing folder in the container and the host has two subdirectories name `input and output.`

This way of mount seems to work for me with out any issues.

Please let me know why scenario 2 failed to work and how to fix it ?

Comment: Try adding the read-write (`:rw`) flag to the end of the output volume mount. Also check if app process inside container is running as root else it might not have permissions to write in output.

Comment: @S.D. , the problem still persist :( , but the host and container has the same user name , uid and gid. Anyother suggestions please

Comment: `NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"` disable SELINUX. Or try adding `:z` flag.

Comment: @KamilCuk, Tried that :z flag and it didnt work for me